# Ubuntu Server 12.04 -> 12.10 Can't do do-release-upgrade

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, release-management

When I log into my Ubuntu 12.04 server, it says:

**New release '12.10' available.
Run `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to it.**

When I run `do-release-upgrade` I get the following:

```
administrator@USNAVLXFTP21:~$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
administrator@USNAVLXFTP21:~$
```

I have run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, and I get:

```
root@USNAVLXFTP21:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am a relative noob, but I have successfully upgraded repeatedly, so I am a little confused as to what I am doing wrong or what I am missing...

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you installed a LTS the update manager defaults to only "long term support versions". To change this open the Software Sources go to the "Updates" tab and change the dropdown next to "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version".